# How to set start day of month view to middle of the month with full calendar

Tags: jquery, date, calendar, fullcalendar

I need to show some events on the calendar but there is no point of having past days on it. So how can set the first row of the full calendar to the current week (or is it even possible)?

I set the start date in the options but it shows the full month from the beginning even though the start date was Feb 18th

ie: for today (Feb 18 Tuesday) the calendar should start from Feb 17 Monday (Instead of Jan 31st Mon) and the last day should be March 16th Sunday. (Instead of March 4th Sunday)

Thanks.

Comment: Would it be useful just to have a column of dates, starting with today, and times for each 'period' in a second column?

Comment: How do fetch the events?

Comment: I am using 'events: '/myfeed.json' option to pull events into calendar.